# Evaluate $F''(4)$ if $F(x) = \int_{4}^{x} \sqrt {t^2+9} \ dt$

Tags: calculus

one of the FTC problems of a Calculus textbook suggests this small problem:

> Evaluate $F''(4)$ if
>
> $$F(x) = \int_{4}^{x} \sqrt {t^2+9} \ dt$$
>
> Ans: $\frac{5}{4}$

I cannot agree with the result. Can anyone confirm the textbook error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "answer" is not correct.

$$F'(x)=\sqrt{x^2+9},\quad F''(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$$
So,
$$F''(4)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{25}}=\frac{4}{5}.$$

Answer (score 1):

No, it's $\frac{4}{5}$. Indeed, 
$$F'(x)=\sqrt{x^2+9}$$ and $$F''(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$$ therefore $F''(4)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{25}}=\frac{4}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

By the Funtamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$F'(x)=\sqrt{x^2+9}$$

Differentiate once again using the chain rule:

$$F''(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+9}}\cdot 2x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+9}}$$

Pluging in $x=4$:
$$F''(x=4)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{25}}=\frac{4}{5}$$

I think the book is wrong.